# Java Regex replaceAll not working as expected

Tags: java, regex, mule, mule-studio

I have the following Java regex (https://.*?/api/FHIR/DSTU2/) to match a URL in the following pattern https://somserver.esm.somedomain.edu/TST/api/FHIR/DSTU2/ in a large JSON result,

and replace it with another URL like 
    https://api.anotherdomain.edu/FHIR/DSTU2/.

The URL I'm replacing occurs multiple times in the JSON result. I am using Java replaceAll function and sometimes it fails and I get the error 'Expected ',' instead of '''. This happens because the JSON result gets messed up during the replacement process, and can't be properly parsed. What's strange is that I used the same JSON result that's failing in a JAVA regex tester, and the regex seems to be working fine. DO you see something out of whack here? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, which JSON Parser do you use? Have you written a Unit-Test or could you provide us with other code to reproduce?

Comment: I think the problem is more of a regex thing than a parser thing. The JSON result is messed up after calling the Java replaceAll function like so JsonString.replaceAll("(https://.*?/api/FHIR/DSTU2/)", hostURI)

Comment: I see, thank you. Can you please provide the JSON payload?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/4jCkbR/3

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/4jCkbR/3/tests

Comment: Can you confirm your source JSON parses without the regex replace, it sounds like the data is bad to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1.Object To String with return class java.lang.String

2.Expression  with below code

```
import java.util.regex.*;

payload=payload.replaceAll("https[:]//.*./api/FHIR/DSTU2/", "https://api.anotherdomain.edu/FHIR/DSTU2/");

return payload;
```

final xml Flow will be

```
     <object-to-string-transformer returnClass="java.lang.String" doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[import java.util.regex.*;

payload=payload.replaceAll("https[:]//.*./api/FHIR/DSTU2/", "https://api.anotherdomain.edu/FHIR/DSTU2/");

return payload;]]></expression-component>

        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am doing the same exact thing: https://ibb.co/kSi6FS the replaceAll method works inside a console application: https://ibb.co/cvpGh7. Also, The JSON file is exactly the same in both environments. it kind of doesn't compute.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a JUnit case for this, trying to reproduce the error. But with the given JSON input below your last link provides, there is no error and everything works fine everytime. Could you try out this test case please?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

public class RegexReplacementTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegexReplacementTest.class);
    private static final String replacement = "https://api.anotherdomain.edu/FHIR/DSTU2/";
    private static final String pattern = "(https://.*?/api/FHIR/DSTU2/)";
    private String json;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        InputStream resourceAsStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/your/test.json");
        json = IOUtils.toString(resourceAsStream);
        resourceAsStream.close();
        validateJson(json);
    }

    @Test
    public void testReplace() {
        String replacedString = json.replaceAll(pattern, replacement);
        validateJson(replacedString);
    }

    private void validateJson(String json) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            objectMapper.readTree(json);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error upon testing json!" , e);
            fail("Error upon testing json! " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what version of Java?

Comment: I used version 1.8

Comment: Same thing here. It works fine in a separate Java project. Unfortunately, i am calling it from MuleSoft ESB. I'm using the same runtime but for some reason replacAll is not working. I'm pulling my hair out here.

Comment: Could it be a problem that just occurs with a different JSON payload?

Comment: No. I've double checked.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Is it possible to get a stacktrace and/or run your program in debugging mode?